# PowerShell (or REST API) to get the status of all Protected Items in an ARM based Azure Site Recovery Vault

Tags: rest, powershell, azure, disaster-recovery

**What I want to Do:-** I want to report the status/Health along with percentages of the data replicated for all the servers in 1 ARM portal based Azure Site Recovery Vault. I am referring to the Protected Items via the Azure Disaster Recovery related Recovery Services (and NOT the Backup items). I want to do this programmatically via PowerShell or using any REST API.

**Problem:-** I am not able to find any API which can provide this data. Are you aware of any way to fetch this data?

**What I have already checked:-** I have already checked the PowerShell cmdlets here and did not found anything useful: [AzureRM.RecoveryServices Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/resourcemanager/azurerm.recoveryservices/v2.3.0/azurerm.recoveryservices). I have also checked the REST APIs available via the [Explorer Tool at https://resources.azure.com/](https://resources.azure.com/).

Any pointers will be helpful for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the API for the exact operation from MS support. The link to the same is here:

[Get specific details about a protected item](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt736938.aspx).

This API give you list of replication protected items in Azure Site Recovery along with Health of each item.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's a REST API for that, consult these links:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/recoveryservices/protecteditemoperationstatuses
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/recoveryservices/protecteditemoperationresults

Comment: Thanks @4c74356b41 for your replies. These APIs provide the status and result of operations on the protected items and not the status of the items itself. I got the API from Microsoft for this which I am posting as the answer. I am trying to find what is Fabric name and protected container name. If you are aware please do let me know. I am upvoting your response as it was helpful.